# HTML charset doing the opposite of what it should do

Tags: html, character-encoding

So I had noticed on my site that unicode characters wouldn't show up, they all displayed as question marks. I had this line in:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

After checking the w3c validator, it showed as UTF-8 as well, yet it still wouldn't work. The solution? Removing that line! I do not understand why this is acting the opposite way as how it should. For example if you go on that page:

http://tideart.com/?id=4eb78742

I put in some unicode text, and it shows fine in any browser here, yet there is no charset line set. If I were to add the line above, all those unicode characters change to ?.

Btw if you check the page now on the w3c validator, it actually says this:

> Before defaulting to windows-1252 the validator also tried to read the
>   content with the following encoding(s), without success: UTF-8.

That text was initially entered through 2 different means. An HTML form, and a text file, saved in UTF8 format. So I don't see why "utf-8" fails so horribly, yet if I actually specify a charset of "windows-1252" it also works.

Anyone care to guess what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that page is encoded using ISO 8859-1. I get the dreaded question mark diamond glyphs if I use UTF-8:

> � kljkjkjk
>
> Le fran�ais de France, appel� parfois fran�ais m�tropolitain ou fran�ais hexagonal ou encore fran�ais norm�, est la vari�t� nationale de la langue fran�aise appartenant � la France. Dans le contexte des comparaisons entre vari�t�s nationales, on pense habituellement au � fran�ais standard de France �

but the following if I use ISO 8859-1:

> € kljkjkjk
>
> Le français de France, appelé parfois français métropolitain ou français hexagonal ou encore français normé, est la variété nationale de la langue française appartenant à la France. Dans le contexte des comparaisons entre variétés nationales, on pense habituellement au « français standard de France »

If you tell the browser that your document is encoded using UTF-8 but it is actually ISO 8859-1 then you'll get a bit of a mess. If you don't specify a character set then the browser will make a guess or use its default; in my case, the default is UTF-8 so I got a mess by default and forcing my browser to use ISO 8859-1 sorted things out.

Answer (score 1):

There is some serious confusion here :-).

You can use a tool like Firebug (in Firefox) or `curl -v` to download the page and see the headers. The server reply is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Nov 2011 07:59:34 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 9659
Content-Type: text/html
```

As you can see, the `Content-Type` header does *not* specify an encoding (which is bad). In that case, browser will try to guess. Your page, as it happens, appears to come encoded as ISO-8859-1, which is the first default in most browsers, thus it works.

If you put "UTF-8" into the META header, the browser will believe you, but show garbage (as the file is in ISO-8859-1).

To fix this, configure your server to send the right encoding with the `Content-Type` header. You can also, additionally, put the encoding into META tags - but make sure it really matches.

The rule in such cases is:

- First, decide which encoding you want to use (in doubt, use UTF-8)
- Make sure you actually *do* send your pages in that encoding (for static pages, just check the .html file on the server; for dynamic pages it depends on the mechanism)
- Make sure your server sends the right encoding in the HTTP headers
- Make sure the META encoding information is correct (this is, strictly speaking, optional, but helpful for people who save your page to a file for offline reading)

Comment: I thought ISO-8859-1 was for ANSI only, not unicode. Either way though, I thought UTF-8 was the default. The way the characters are entered is through a web form in Firefox, which is submitted to a php file that adds it to the database. I'm not sure how to make it so the text is sent in UTF format.

Comment: "I thought ISO-8859-1 was for ANSI only, not unicode." Well, yes, sort of. I assume by "ANSI" you mean one of the ANSI codepages of Windows. In that case, yes, ISO-8859-1 is roughly equal to CP 1252 (but some characters differ). Unicode is a superset of both.

Comment: @Dendory: As to the encoding of text sent via a web form: I'm no expert in that area, but I believe normally the browser will send the contents of a web form with the same character encoding that the page came in. So if you serve your pages as UTF-8, the browser should submit forms with text in UTF-8 as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to just set the charset as UTF8, you must save the page as utf8 as well (configure your text editor).